# Not able to read Mysql data on a web page using HTML

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the database that is interacting with Android App also.

My other database tables data are working but one of the table is not able to be fetched on the HTML page.

[image: Database with tables problem in order]

[image: Table order structure]

[image: Error]

> Error: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\trydata01\testt.php on line 39 0 result

**PHP CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table with database</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            color: #d96459;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th{
            background-color: #588c7e;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>OrderId</th>
            <th>OrderStatus</th>
            <th>OrderPrice</th>
            <th>OrderDetail</th>
            <th>OrderComment</th>
            <th>OrderComment1</th>
            <th>UserPhone</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "wcfood01");
        if ($conn-> connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error );
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * from order";
        $result = $conn-> query($sql);

        if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>". $row["OrderId"] ."</td><td>". $row["OrderStatus"] ."</td><td>". $row["OrderPrice"] . "</td><td>". $row["OrderDetail"] . "</td><td>". $row["OrderComment"] ."</td><td>". $row["OrderComment1"] ."</td><td>". $row["UserPhone"] ."</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        else{
            echo "0 result";
        }

        $conn-> close();
        ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do `$conn-> connect_error` or `$conn-> query` do, where are they defined?

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) You are not checking for connection errors properly, and in fact you do not need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Romove the space between object and function :**

```
$conn-> connect_error
$conn-> connect_error
$result-> num_rows
$result-> fetch_assoc()
```

Changes :

```
$conn->connect_error
$conn->connect_error
$result->num_rows
$result->fetch_assoc()
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Table with database</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
                color: #d96459;
                font-family: monospace;
                font-size: 25px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            th{
                background-color: #588c7e;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>OrderId</th>
                <th>OrderStatus</th>
                <th>OrderPrice</th>
                <th>OrderDetail</th>
                <th>OrderComment</th>
                <th>OrderComment1</th>
                <th>UserPhone</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "wcfood01");
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed:". $conn->connect_error );
            }
            $sql = "SELECT * from order";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["OrderId"] ."</td><td>". $row["OrderStatus"] ."</td><td>". $row["OrderPrice"] . "</td><td>". $row["OrderDetail"] . "</td><td>". $row["OrderComment"] ."</td><td>". $row["OrderComment1"] ."</td><td>". $row["UserPhone"] ."</td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            }
            else{
                echo "0 result";
            }

            $conn-> close();
            ?>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what was wrong and what you changed instead of just posting code? Thx

Comment: Romove the space between object and function -> like $result-> num_rows

Comment: This would not cause any problems, especially the one mentioned in the question. This answer is wrong.